# Javascript Singleton with Closure explanation

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, singleton, closures

**Intro:** I start to read Javascript Patterns book and can't grasp one example. It's pretty big so I'll try to explain it briefly before getting you a code.

**Examples explanation:** So what they try to do is to define singleton with help of Closure. The first piece of code is pretty simple, but it has one significant drawback - we can't redefine prototype after creating the first instance of `Universe`.

**Question:** *Could someone explain me how does the second example ('Good' singleton) code manage to change prototype after first constructor call?*

**'Bad' singleton:**

```
function Universe() {
    var instance = this;
    this.start_time = 0; 
    this.bang = "Big";
    Universe = function () {
        return instance; 
    };
}
// testing
Universe.prototype.nothing = true;
var uni = new Universe();
Universe.prototype.everything = true;
var uni2 = new Universe();
uni.nothing; // true 
uni2.nothing; // true 
//AS YOU CAN SEE ALL CHANGES TO UNIVERSE PROTOTYPE HAVE NO RESULT AFTER FIRST CONSTRUCTOR CALL
uni.everything; // undefined 
uni2.everything; // undefined
```

And then they solve the problem with code below:

**'Good' singleton:**

```
function Universe() {
    var instance;
    Universe = function Universe() {
       return instance; 
    };
    Universe.prototype = this;
    instance = new Universe();
    instance.constructor = Universe;
    instance.start_time = 0; 
    instance.bang = "Big";
    return instance; 
}
// testing
Universe.prototype.nothing = true;
var uni = new Universe();
//QUESTION: how does it manage to change the prototype of singleton?!
Universe.prototype.everything = true;
var uni2 = new Universe();
uni.nothing && uni.everything && uni2.nothing && uni2.everything; // true
```

**The same question in other words:** why in the first code snippet `uni.everything == false` and `uni2.everything == false` but in the second one `uni.everything == true` and `uni2.everything == true`? As for me, they should be `false` in both cases

Comment: Of course it is, it's always returning the instance created the first time.

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy which question have you just answered?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **Note:** please feel free to reword this answer to make it sound better, I probably haven't explained it well.

### Example 1 ("Bad" singleton)

In your first example:

```
function Universe() {
    var instance = this;
    this.start_time = 0; 
    this.bang = "Big";
    Universe = function () {
        return instance; 
    };
}
```

When you call `new Universe()` the second time, it returns the `instance` stored from the first time (when the global `Universe` constructor was replaced), not a new object. This is why any changes to `Universe.prototype` have no effect.

### Example 2 ("Good" singleton)

Your second example is a bit more complicated. The first time you call it, `this` refers to the object initially created, which means it has the prototype with the `nothing` property. As this object is now the prototype for the instance returned, the `nothing` property is inherited.

Because now when you call `new Universe()` a second time it is returning the result of `instance = new Universe()` from the first time, any changes to it are also kept with it.

Because you returned `instance` in the original `Universe` function, `uni` is the same object as `uni2`.

This would have the same effect as doing this:

```
var Universe2;

function Universe() {
    Universe2 = function () {
         return instance; 
    };
    Universe2.prototype = this;
    var instance = new Universe2();
    instance.constructor = Universe2;
    instance.start_time = 0; 
    instance.bang = "Big";
    return instance;
}

Universe.prototype.nothing = true;

var uni = new Universe();

Universe2.prototype.everything = true;

var uni2 = new Universe2();
```

And then the final object would look like this:

```
==========================
= Object.prototype       =
=  - hasOwnProperty: ... =
=  - toString: ...       =
=  - ...                 =
==========================
            ^
            |
            |
            |
            |
==========================
= Universe.prototype:    =
=   - nothing: true      =
==========================
            ^
            |
            |
            |
            |
==========================
= Instance of Universe:  =
=  - everything: true    =
==========================
            ^
            |
            |
            |
            |
==========================
= Instance of Universe2: =
=  - start_time: 0       =
=  - bang: "Big"         =
==========================
```